# Django variables with a list of values

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, many-to-many

I was wondering if there was a better way to implement this: I have a model with several fields. Each field needs to have multiple date ranges with corresponding values. So for example, I might have a class "Person" with a boolean variable "Hungry" that's true from 9am-12pm, false from 12pm-2pm, and then true again from 2-5pm. Any times not covered by my date ranges would just be a default value.

One way to implement this would be to turn Hungry into a separate class with value, start-time, and end-time. Then Person would have a many to many relationship with Hungry. Is there a better way to implment this that doesn't create a table for each variable, but still allows for easy lookups?

Comment: What types of lookups do you require? all persons hungry at a given time? all persons hungry at a given time-interval? all intervals a person is hungry at? whether a person is hungry at a given time? all of the above?

Comment: Yes, all of the above. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a foreign key instead of a many to many relationship.

```
Class Person(models.Model):
    #...

Class Hungry(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKeyField(Person)
    start = models. DateTimeField()
    end = models. DateTimeField()
    hungry = models. BooleanField()
```

I guess you could replace the `person` field on `Hungry` with a `CharField`, so as to squeeze this into one table, but that's poor DB design. It should really be two separate tables.

Comment: CharField doesn't seem like a good idea. Good call on the ForeignKey. I guess each variable will just have to be a different class.